# Communication between coroutines breaks when adding "Flow.scan()" to the chain

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have several coroutines communicating through channels and I have some items not arriving into one of them. It looks like whenever I introduce a `scan` operator this starts to occur.

I have distilled the situation to this "minimal" example:

```kotlin
runBlocking {
  val signals = BroadcastChannel<Unit>(capacity = Channel.BUFFERED)
  val extraValues = BroadcastChannel<Int>(capacity = Channel.BUFFERED)
  launch {
    signals.asFlow()
      .onEach {
        println("received signal, emitting values")
        extraValues.send(33); extraValues.send(44)
      }
      .collect()
  }
  launch {
    merge(extraValues.asFlow(), flowOf(2, 3))
      .scan(1, { acc, v -> v })
      .collect {
        println("received $it")
        if (it == 1) {
          signals.offer(Unit)
        }
      }
  }
}
```

The code above prints:

```
received 1
received signal, emitting values
received 2
received 3
```

So, `33` and `44` are emitted, but never received.

Now, if I make `1` emitted by `flowOf(1,2,3)` and remove `scan`, everything works fine:

```
    // ... code above unchanged ...
    merge(extraValues.asFlow(), flowOf(1, 2, 3)) // <- added 1
      // <- removed scan
      .collect {
        println("received $it")
        if (it == 1) {
          signals.offer(Unit)
        }
      }
```

This prints:

```
received 1
received 2
received 3
received signal, emitting values
received 33
received 44
```

Can anyone explain what happens here and what can I do to make the version with `scan` work and receive values emitted by `extraValues`?